# Improve performance of a hashtable

Tags: performance, search, data-structures, insert, hashtable

I've to search/insert up to 1000000 elements in a Hash Table getting input from a txt file and I need to do it efficiently. I wrote some code but it takes several seconds when input grows up.

My structure is a vector of list of Nodes. Hash keys are strings of lengths 5. Hash funct is djb (items seem to be uniformly distributed).

That's the only funct I use:

```
void searchAndInsert (const string& key)
{
unsigned int i = Hash (key) % size;

for (list<Node>::iterator it = v[i].begin(); it != v[i].end (); it++)
    if (it->getNome () == key)
        return;

    v[i].push_back (Node (key));
    ++elements;
}
```

How can I improve it?

Thanks all and sorry for my bad english! :D

Comment: Throwing a million rows into a hash table seems like a really bad idea to me.  Assuming you have to do this more than once, I would bulkcopy into a database (something that can nicely handle a million rows) and then query what you need out of the data.

Comment: How big is the hash table you're using? Regardless of whether it is uniformly distributed or not, if it's too small, it will be slow. Also, a uniformly distributed hash function doesn't say much if many input strings are the same. I'd suggest considering a BST-based implementation instead (C++ right? So `std::set` or `std::map`).

Comment: I would start by profiling. Could be that the actual reading from the file takes more time than the whole hash-table business. Second: take a look at the generated code. Maybe the iterators do strange things. Last minor point: inserting at the beginning could force an unneeded cache miss; insertion at the tail won't since you are already at the tail.

Comment: Try using an already-written hash table implementation rather than writing your own. There is one in Boost, as well as in some cases significantly more performant closed hash ones in [Google Sparsehash](http://code.google.com/p/google-sparsehash/) and [MCT](https://launchpad.net/libmct/).

Comment: @doublep: unless you know what you are doing, and want to spend some time on it. The success of http://sourceforge.net/projects/wakkerbot/ wakkebot is mostly a result of it's finely tuned handbuilt hash tables (there are two). I just ran a profile: and less then 1% of its 7 second running time was spent in the >600K entry dictionary of tokens. (That is probably 600K inserts plus a few K lookups.)

Comment: +1 to wildplasser -- You haven't given sufficient information to solve your problem, likely because you don't know where the actual bottleneck is. So, as most improvements go, continue to find out more until the answer is apparent.

Comment: There is another improvement you could do *iff you know the final size* of the hash table, you could create the initial table with the right size (or a bit more). Resizing typically will cause a doubling of the required operations, plus a lot of memory fragmentation, plus the implied latency (I don't know if the OQ has RT requirements)